# How do I get started developing dapps on Moonbeam and Moonriver?

Tags: moonbeam, moonriver

What's the best way to get set up and start developing dapps on Moonbeam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly announced Moonbeam academy is free and available here:

https://academy.moonbeam.network/ and is also available in [Chinese](https://moonbeam-china.teachable.com/p/moonbeam-v2-0). (Not all modules are translated yet)

The Moonbuilders course curriculum includes a welcome lesson to prepare participants with background knowledge about Substrate, Polkadot, and Moonbeam. There are eight lessons beginning with education about the ecosystem itself and moving toward the application of developer tools like Remix, Solidity, Truffle, and Hardhat. The course provides guided opportunities to test skills and experiment with Web 3 applications, including Ethers.js, price feeds, precompiles, and building a staking DAO. More content will be added soon to cover Moonbeam technology updates and new integrations in the ecosystem.

[Read the official announcement](https://moonbeam.network/blog/moonbuilders-academy-is-now-open/)